# InfiniteScroll inside MagnificPopup

Tags: jquery, ajax, delegates, infinite-scroll, magnific-popup

I'm using Infinite Scroll (by Metafizzy) **inside** a Magnific Popup. This is my current code:

```
$('.conversation__view').infiniteScroll({
    path: '.nextPage',
    append: '.message__single',
    history: false,
    hideNav: '.conversation__view ul.pagination'
});
```

The navigation is hidden but the next posts are not being loaded. I tried changing the `scrollThreshold` value and even tried with a button and `loadOnScroll: false` but nothing happens.

I have the same script working on another part of the page, just not inside a Magnific Popup.

The Popup is initialised like that:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: '/messages/list',
    },
    type: 'ajax',
    ajax: {
        settings: null,
        cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur'
    }
});
```

Inside this list are links, that are opening a conversation details view, opened like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#messages__overlay a.single', function(ev){
    $('#messages__overlay .messages__content').html('Loading...').load($(this).attr('href');
});
```

The `.load` has a callback (not shown here) where I initialise infiniteScroll, as seen in the first code example.

Any other ideas I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware that I needed this option in order for this to work, but that's what I needed: https://infinite-scroll.com/options.html#elementscroll